# Prepared statement giving different results to query in client

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, abstraction

**Update:** If I stop the WHERE clause from parameterizing the second operand so that the query PHP runs is:

```
SELECT 5c9_dpd_users.id, 5c9_dpd_users.username, 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id, 
5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.usergroup_name, 5c9_dpd_users.email FROM 5c9_dpd_users,    
5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms WHERE 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id
ORDER BY username asc
```

the correct results are returned.  However, if the WHERE clause is parameterized like so:

```
WHERE 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = ? ORDER BY username asc
```

then the incorrect results are returned; it seems to convert the parameterized argument to '5' and return the results that have an ID of 5.  Does anybody know why this happens, or how I may find a workaround?  Thank you.

**Original Post:**

I've created a database abstraction layer as part of a wider system I am writing.  I am currently using its MySQL implementation and a very strange error is occurring where the query generated by the application runs correctly if I C+P it in the console, but produces incorrect results when parameters are bound etc., through the PHP functions.

Firstly, here is the relevant portion of my DB schema:

[image: DB schema for question]

Having created some debugging output inside my database class, I am given the following information about the query it produces and executes (with `stmt::execute`).

```
SELECT 5c9_dpd_users.id, 5c9_dpd_users.username, 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id,
5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.usergroup_name, 5c9_dpd_users.email FROM 5c9_dpd_users, 
5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms WHERE 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = ? ORDER BY username asc

Array
(
  [0] => i
  [1] => 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id
)
```

The above shows the generated query as printed to the debugging page, followed by the value (and type) of the placeholdered parameter.  Putting the table/column name into the query and running it in the console gives me the following correct output:

[image: ///]

As you can just about see, the usergroup_name is different for each usergroup_id.  However, the following code does not work:

```
// I have executed the statement and bound the result up to this point.

self::$stmt->bind_result($test1, $test2, $test3, $test4, $test5);
    while (self::$stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "ID: $test1<br>Username: $test2 <br>Usergroup ID: $test3 Usergroup Name: $test4 <br> Email: $test5<br><br>";
    }
```

The above code is simplified somewhat but it exemplifies the problem just as well.  If you examine the below output from the above code, you will see that the usergroup name remains identical despite the differing usergroup ID.

```
ID: 7
Username: ADD 
Usergroup ID: 1 Usergroup Name: se 
Email: test@test.com

ID: 1
Username: New User 
Usergroup ID: 2 Usergroup Name: se 
Email: test@test.com

ID: 4
Username: test user 
Usergroup ID: 1 Usergroup Name: se 
Email: test@test.com

ID: 2
Username: User2 
Usergroup ID: 5 Usergroup Name: se 
Email: p@b.com

ID: 6
Username: username here 
Usergroup ID: 1 Usergroup Name: se 
Email: test@test.com

ID: 5
Username: xyz 
Usergroup ID: 3 Usergroup Name: se 
Email: pete@pete.com
```

I am completely at a loss!  I first thought this to be a problem with my database abstraction class, but I'm not so sure any more since I've essentially removed all abstraction and am still getting the problem.  I'm unsure what other information to provide, but if you would like more details on something I will happily provide them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your query :

```
SELECT 5c9_dpd_users.id, 5c9_dpd_users.username, 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id, 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.usergroup_name, 5c9_dpd_users.email
FROM 5c9_dpd_users, 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms
WHERE 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = ? ORDER BY username asc
```

You are never joining your tables on some id's you should do something like this

```
SELECT 5c9_dpd_users.id, 5c9_dpd_users.username, 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id, 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.usergroup_name, 5c9_dpd_users.email
FROM 5c9_dpd_users users
LEFT JOIN 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms cms ON cms.id = users.cms_usergroup_id
WHERE 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = ? ORDER BY username asc
```

You have to join your group table and user table see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: I'll admit I'm not great at SQL, but I don't quite follow; the query I showed above - with the 'shorthand' join syntax - does work fine in the console.  Thus, it can't be a problem with the query itself, can it?

Comment: Do you want to get all the user being in the user_group_cms with the specify id? And can i see the request you're executing in the console because we can't see it in the screenshot

Comment: I would like PHP to perform the query with the same results as running the query in the MySQL console does.  As in my example above - the second screenshot - that is the output the console produces, and it is correct.  The usergroup_name is provided along with every cms_usergroup_id in the users field.  I've never seen a query behave differently in PHP to the Console before!  Very confused.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The request I am executing in the console is as follows: SELECT 5c9_dpd_users.id, 5c9_dpd_users.username, 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id, 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.usergroup_name, 5c9_dpd_users.email FROM 5c9_dpd_users, 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms WHERE 5c9_dpd_usergroups_cms.id = 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id ORDER BY username asc

Comment: Ok it makes way more sens why your shorthand join works, I thought you were putting random values ... Ok anyway why are you binding two values `Array
(
  [0] => i
  [1] => 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id
)` While you have only one ? in your request ?

Comment: I am not binding two values; the array you see there is debugging from my system.  The first parameter of any prepared statement run by my class is a list of the types expected by the placeholders; it might look like 'iiss', for example, if I had four placeholders that were two integers followed by two strings.  That first argument is not ever binded to the query.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: HAHAHAHAAHAH :) You're binding system is converting 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id to 5 :) which is the group_id of se maybe you should set it as a string

Comment: Hm, I typecast it to 's' instead of 'i' but no difference.  I'll look into it some more and post what - if anything - I find.  Thanks for the help... :)

Comment: I have just tried something.  I removed the paramaterization of the placeholder argument (? becomes 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id in the query PHP runs) and it works!  Do you happen to know why it doesn't allow me to placeholder 5c9_dpd_users.cms_usergroup_id?

Comment: Not to worry!  Thanks VERY much for your help, you've really led me on the right path! :)